# How to do recursive vectorized calculations in pandas DataFrame via columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, vectorization

Edit: I have altered the sample data so that the 5th row is now gone due to an error in the sample.

Assume that we a directed graph `G = (V, E)` of edges `E` and vertices `V`. Assume that we have a Pandas DataFrame describing which nodes `(u, v)`are connected to each other and the value/weight of the corresponding edge `e`. Let the following be a representation of such a DataFrame.

```
#   from   to   weight
-----------------------
0     0     1     1.0
1     1     2     0.5
2     2     3     0.2     
3     0     4     1.3
4     4     5     0.9
```

Is it possible to somehow add a column with accumulated weights, such that for instance row 2 has an accumulated weight value of `1.7=0.2+0.5+1.0` since we have a path `0->1->2->3`? Preferably in a vectorized so that the calculation scales. In other words, we should get the following DataFrame.

```
#   from   to   weight    accumulated
-------------------------------------
0     0     1     1.0      1.0
1     1     2     0.5      1.5
2     2     3     0.2      1.7   
3     0     4     1.3      1.3
4     4     5     0.9      2.2
```

We can assume that there is no other path to vertex `3` since the DataFrame is made such that only shortest paths are included.

I have thus far written the following piece of code that uses `DataFrame.apply`, which is not a vectorized approach. Here I store / cache previously calculated accumulated values in a dictionary called `accum_map`.

```
def __set_accum(self, row):
    search = row["to"]
    if search in self.accum_map:
        return self.accum_map[search]
    from_node = row["from"]
    old_from = self.df[self.df["to"] == from_node].get("from")
    old_from = None if old_from.empty else old_from.values[0]
    weight = row["weight"]
    self.accum_map[search] = self.__set_accum({"to": from, "from": old_from}) + weight
    return self.accum_mapp[search]

def set_accumulated(self):
    self.df["accumulated"] = self.df.apply(func=self.__set_timestamp, axis=1)
```

Comment: can you explain how row 3,4,5 are calculated? What I don't understand is how row 3,4,5 get accumulated = 1.3, 2.2 and 1.9

Comment: Row 3: The complete path ending at 4 is just 0->4. Hence, the accumulated weight is 1.3
Row 4: The complete path ending at 5 is 0->4->5. Hence, the accumulated weight is 2.2=1.3+0.9.
I have removed row 5 since I can now see that it came with an error.

Comment: Sr I give up, I dont understand what you want

Comment: @PTQuoc: As I tried to write above, if I have a path like 0->2->6->7->9, then the edges (0,2), (2,6), (6,7), (7,9) each have an individual weight. And I want some quick way of accumulating the weights, so that:
1) the row of (0,2) gets the weight of (0,2)
2) the row of (2,6) gets the accumulated weight of (0,2) and (2,6)
3) the row of (6,7) get the accumulated weight of (0,2), (2,6) and (6,7)
4) the row of (7,9) get the accumulated weight of (0,2), (2,6), (6,7) and (7,9)
So (as I have written in my code above) I conceptually need some recursion that traverses the path via the DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with your dataset. I re-create another example here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'from':[0,2,3,1,0],
                   'to':[1,2,4,4,2],
                   'val':[10,20,30,40,50]})
```

Here if you do not have to groupby, then it is easier to exact `series` outside, perform indexing sum then add back to main dataframe.

```
# Extract value:
s = df['val']
st = df['from']
gt = (df['to']+1)

# Perform cumsum by 
out = list()
for i,j in zip(st,gt):
    out.append(s[i:j].sum())

# Add `new` col from result
df['new'] = out
```

Comment: I have corrected the dataset. But remember that the paths can have arbitrary length. That is way the value should be "accumulated". Not just the sum of up to 2 values.